# I need to make cross domain requests server side

Tags: php, cross-domain

I have 2 different servers of mine.

I am using one server for managing all the data, and the system.

The other server is just for giving user points.

I need to to make a call in my first server on server side in php, 
to the second server, and to get response from the server.

Example in PHP:

```
$response = getDataFromOtherServer("http://otherServer.com");
// manipulate response
```

Comment: do you have access to both servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
$response = fopen("http://otherServer.com?var1=some&var2=thing","r");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between getting data from 2 servers by changing the connection to those servers like for host 1

> mysql_connect('host1','username','password')

execute data for host1 and save. Now when you need data from host2 connect to that and manipulate your data

Answer (score 0):

use REST API from Phil Sturgeon ->

**REST SERVER:**
https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

**REST CLIENT:**
https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a web service on your data server, you can use CURL to make HTTP requests to that service. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php